# Getting an equation involving logarithm into explicit form

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

I am at the final part of a problem where I have derived

$t+c=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\log\left(\frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4-2x^2}}\right)$

where $c$ is a constant, and now I need to express it in explicit form $x(t)$. Of course I can get rid of the logarithm and get an exponent on the left hand side, but beyond that  point I have tried lots of different things (including using surds for the fraction which doesn't seem to help) but can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: It becomes a quadratic equation of $x.$

Comment: Put $K=e^{\sqrt{2} (t+c)}$ to simplify the algebra towards getting the quadratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\inv#1{\frac{1}{#1}}$
$$t+c=\inv{\sqrt{2}}\log\left(\frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4-2x^2}}\right)$$
$$e^{\sqrt 2(t+c)}=\frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4-2x^2}}$$
As a comment suggested, we do $K=e^{\sqrt 2(t+c)}$
$$K(2+\sqrt{4-2x^2})=x$$
$$\frac{x-2K}{K}=\sqrt{4-2x^2}$$
Now we square both sides
$$\frac{x^2-4Kx+4K^2}{K^2}=4-2x^2$$

Comment: I've accepted the answer because I get what to do (get $x$ in quadratic form) however I think you have a mistake: after squaring both sides don't we get $\frac{x^2+4k^2-4kx}{k^2}=4-2x^2 \implies x^2(1+2k^2)-4kx=0$?

Comment: You are probably correct, I'll just remove the final part, it's probably not helpful anyway.